# Shopify - Product Tabs

Tags: html, css, shopify

I have the following code to add a tab to product pages, which will not be static or the same for all other products.

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
  <a href="#tab-description" class="selected">{{'products.product.description' | t}}</a>
  {%- if product.description contains "Videos" -%}
  <a href="#tab-video">
    {{ product.description | split: '<h6>' | last | remove: '<h6>' | split: '</h6>' | first}}
  </a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.reviews_enable -%}
  <a href="#tab-review" id="product-reviews-a" class="">{{'products.product.customer_reviews' | t}}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_1 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-1">{{ settings.product_tab_title_1 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_2 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-2">{{ settings.product_tab_title_2 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_3 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-3">{{ settings.product_tab_title_3 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_4 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-4">{{ settings.product_tab_title_4 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
</div>

<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" itemprop="description
{{product.description}}</div>
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .tab-content {
    max-width: 80% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
</style>

{%- if product.description contains "Videos" -%}
<div id="tab-video" class="tab-content">{{ product.description | split: '<h6>' | last | remove: '<h6>' | split: '</h6>' | first}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.reviews_enable -%}
<div id="tab-review" class="tab-content"><div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{product.metafields.spr.reviews}}</div></div>
{%- endif -%}  
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_1 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-1" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_1].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_2 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-2" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_2].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_3 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-3" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_3].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_4 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-4" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_4].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
```

All other Tabs are created by the theme by default.
The one I want to add is the *'Videos'* tab, but how do I remove `<h6>Videos</h6>`, and any text after it, in the main *'Description'* tab?
And how do I make anything under `<h6>Videos</h6>` appear under the *'Videos'* tab?

Current output:

[image: Description Tab]

[image: Videos Tab]

**Videos** and **Hi** should not show in *'Description'* tab.

As you can see, **Hi** doesn't show in *'Videos'* tab, and that where I want it to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, nevermind me. I got it working with the following:

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs">
  <a href="#tab-description" class="selected">{{'products.product.description' | t}}</a>
  {%- if product.description contains "Videos" -%}
  <a href="#tab-video">
    {{ product.description | split: '<h6>' | last | remove: '<h6>' | split: '</h6>' | first}}
  </a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.reviews_enable -%}
  <a href="#tab-review" id="product-reviews-a" class="">{{'products.product.customer_reviews' | t}}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_1 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-1">{{ settings.product_tab_title_1 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_2 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-2">{{ settings.product_tab_title_2 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_3 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-3">{{ settings.product_tab_title_3 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
  {%- if settings.product_tab_content_4 != blank -%}
  <a href="#tab-cus-4">{{ settings.product_tab_title_4 }}</a>
  {%- endif -%}
</div>

<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">{{product.description | split: '<h6>' | first | remove: '<h6>' }}</div></div>
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .tab-content {
    max-width: 80% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
</style>

{%- if product.description contains "Videos" -%}
<div id="tab-video" class="tab-content">{{product.description | split: '</h6>' | last }}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.reviews_enable -%}
<div id="tab-review" class="tab-content"><div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{product.metafields.spr.reviews}}</div></div>
{%- endif -%}  
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_1 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-1" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_1].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_2 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-2" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_2].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_3 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-3" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_3].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
{%- if settings.product_tab_content_4 != blank -%}
<div id="tab-cus-4" class="tab-content">{{- pages[settings.product_tab_content_4].content -}}</div>
{%- endif -%}
```

It was `<div id="tab-description" class="tab-content" itemprop="description">{{product.description | split: '<h6>' | first | remove: '<h6>' }}</div></div>` and `<a href="#tab-video">{{ product.description | split: '<h6>' | last | remove: '<h6>' | split: '</h6>' | first}}`